# How to select data between given interval of time from SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel, sql-server-2008, vb6

I have following data in SQL [image: SQL Data i am having]

Need sql queue:

I have 10 tags, it is continuously logging to SQl at every 10 Seconds of intervals.
Now i want create report like.....User will provide time interval and tag name on that basis it will select data from table & display in Excel
Suppose My inputs are :
*interval is* **2016-09-21 14.00.00** to **2016-09-21 22.00.00**
*Tag Name is* : **system\Year**
I want following output:[image: output result]
**Suppose record is not present at that time, then i need blank/Zero value.**
I want to create this in VB6.

Comment: This is a line copy/pasted from a Excel VBA SQL spreadsheet I worked on a little while ago: `AND d1_17.ddeath>={ts '" & StartDate & " 00:00:00'} AND d1_17.ddeath<={ts '" & StopDate & " 00:00:00'}` StartDate and StopDate were user-selected parameters

Comment: Am I missing something here? What is wrong with a SQL query SELECT fields FROM table WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN '2016-09-21 14:00'  AND '2016-09-21 22:00')

Comment: @jac It will select all data between 14:00 to 22:00. (like 14:10:25)
I need data for 14:00, 15:00, 16:00 ..... 22:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an SQL statement that selects the fields you want from the records you want. You said you are trying to select only the even minutes so the SQL is something like

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM table
WHERE
    (DateAndTime BETWEEN '2016-09-21 14:00' AND '2016-09-21 22:00')
AND
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, DateAndTime) % 60 = 0)
```

If you need even seconds also just add another AND to the the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM table
WHERE
    (DateAndTime BETWEEN '2016-09-21 14:00' AND '2016-09-21 22:00')
AND
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, DateAndTime) % 60 = 0)
AND
    (DATEPART(SECOND, DateAndTime) % 60 = 0)
```

To answer the question in the last comment, I have worked up a SQL query that works. It may be that if you post your exact requirements with a SQL tag and ignore the vb6, vba tags because this is really all SQL and has nothing to do with the environment running it, that you'll get a better answer. This will work. I would suggest incorporating this into a stored procedure.

This works by creating a table variable and populating it with the possible time values that can be returned. It then left joins the table you want to query. The result is a null value from the second table when there is no record to join on.

```
--select records on the hour from 8:00 to 5:00
DECLARE @MinTime datetime = '2016-9-9 09:00'   --need to parameterize
DECLARE @MaxTime datetime = '2016-9-10 17:00'  --need to parameterize
DECLARE @TempTime datetime = @MinTime

DECLARE @Times TABLE
(
    TimeValue datetime
)
WHILE @TempTime <= @MaxTime
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Times
    (
        TimeValue
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @TempTime
    )
    SET @TempTime = DATEADD(hour, 1, @TempTime)
END

SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(10), TimeRange.TimeValue, 101) AS [Date]
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), TimeRange.TimeValue, 108) AS [Time]
    ,ISNULL(Tag, 'NA')
    ,ISNULL(Value, 0)
FROM
    @Times TimeRange
LEFT JOIN
    table
ON
    (CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), table.DateAndTime, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(HOUR, table.DateAndTime)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, table.DateAndTime)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(SECOND, table.DateAndTime))) = TimeRange.TimeValue)
WHERE
    (TimeRange.TimeValue BETWEEN @MinTime AND @MaxTime)
```

Comment: i only want select data hourly...skip other data....like in a day i want 24 values

Comment: @user3868044 And that is what the queries above give you.

Comment: ...Thank you so much...it was working superb....Thanks alot.

I have one more requirement : Suppose i have selected 8 hours time period, then i need 8 values. Suppose for some time if value is not present, then i need to show Null/0/Blank.

Comment: Hello, @jac
 have one more requirement : Suppose i have selected 8 hours time period, then i need 8 values. Suppose for some time if value is not present, then i need to show Null/0/Blank.

Comment: @user3868044 Notice the ISNULL in the query. That is what that handles. You may have to do some of the work yourself.